# Get rid of Pop/Click with AKPlayer playing a low sample

Tags: audiokit

I'm creating a sort of drum pad app, and it seems like AKPlayer is the best of many classes available in AudioKit for playing my samples.

Trouble is, when I start playing a low-frequency (bass note) sample, there's always a clicking sound (or "pop") when playing the sample!

This can be easily heard by running an unmodified "Mixing Nodes" demo from the **AudioKit Playgrounds**. Turn down the volume on everything but the Bass, and you'll notice the clicking every time the Bass sample loops.

Of note: I played with the "bass loop.wav" file included in the examples and I slightly faded in, and out, the sample, so that the waveform starts and ends at zero. When I do this, I don't get the clicking in between repeats. So that leads me to believe that a sample starting or ending on a non-zero causes a click.

The problem is, the samples I have don't all start on a zero.

Even more importantly, I want the user to be able to 'hit' a note and play that note repeatedly, so for instance you might have a bass note "baaaaaaaaaaah" but I hit it several times so it stutters like "ba-ba-baaaaaaaaaaah".  If I stop and restart playing the AKPlayer, I get a click — perhaps because I'm transitioning immediately from a non-zero sample number to the new sample starting up.

You can play with this concept in the same playground, just turn off `isLooping` on the bass, and add the following lines:

```
        addView(AKButton(title: "Bass") { button in
            bass.stop();  bass.play()
        })
```

I've played with `stopEnvelopeTime` on the AKPlayer, but that doesn't seem to work as expected. When I tap on a pad in the app, I don't want to add latency to wait for the currently playing sample to fade out before I start playing the sample again.

Is there some better API that I can use to make a sample be polyphonic with *itself* so that when I hit a sample that's currently playing, the currently-playing sample fades out, but then mixed in, the sample starts up again *immediately*?  And, without clicking?

Comment: have you tried adding a very short fade in to your player?

Comment: Sound is basically a continuous function, and whenever we introduce a discontinuity in an audio chain like going from zero to a sample without gradual increments, a "pop" occurs. This happens in any digital audio processing software (Max/MSP, SuperCollider, CSound, etc.). As for the last part of the question about playing samples in a polyphonic way, you could look into AKSampler.